# Changing overbrace width in mathjax?

Tags: braces, mathjax

The following code

```
A_1, A_2,\underbrace{A_3,\overbrace{A_4}^{\text{over}}, A_5}_{\text{under}}, A_6, A_7
```

yields

[image: before]

How can I change it to get:

[image: after]

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: you've more `ooo` in your output than your input, it is helpful to make them match.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: In `LaTeX` this problem was solved using the `mathtools` package and the *macro* `\mathclap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments pure mathjax questions are off topic, but if you can phrase the question such that the anwser involves TeX you are Ok,

unfortunately there are various ways in latex of centring some text whilst hiding its width, but none seem to be supported in mathjax, this sort of half works but you have to split the text into two "by hand" and

```
\(  A_1, A_2,\underbrace{A_3,\overbrace{A_4}^{\llap{oooo}\rlap{ver}} A_5}_{\text{under}}, A_6, A_7\)
```